# squid proxy dont load only one site , dont SSL VERIFY HOST

Tags: linux, ubuntu, squid, openssl, curl

squid proxy don't load only one site, don't have a problem with other websites

I think this problem from SSL VERIFY HOST on squid.

I use this code on squid config but don't fix my problem:
Source: https://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Intercept/SslBumpExplicit

```
sslproxy_cert_error allow all
sslproxy_flags DONT_VERIFY_PEER
```

i test for open this website with CURL:

```
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to
```

i **FIXED** this problem with this code on PHP CURL:

```
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
```

i test for open this website with WGET:

```
--2018-09-03 19:17:31--  https://destenationWebsite.com
Resolving destenationWebsite.com (destenationWebsite.com)... ip
Connecting to destenationWebsite.com(destenationWebsite.com)|ip|:443... connected.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

Comment: It is not for you to fix every broken website. That web site has [so many problems with their SSL setup](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=ebanking.bankmellat.ir), it's surprising if anybody can access it.

Comment: @michael-hampton , how to fix this problem on Ubuntu , I could fix it with php , but i have problem on Squid proxy , Curl , Wget ...

Comment: You can't fix someone else's web site. You did not "fix" it on PHP, you simply connected insecurely. Now someone can put up a fake bank website, and your PHP code will blindly connect to it. This is a very good way to lose a lot of money. Do you really want to be able to connect to a fake bank website via squid?

Comment: @michael-hampton i have a proxy server and use Squid Proxy, but this website don't load, this is only my problem , i dont have problem for load other website.

Comment: No, the problem is with the website. It is not your problem. DO NOT TRY TO DO THIS. You will risk losing all the money in your bank account.

Comment: Mr. Michael Hampton you right this problem from the website, but now I don't load this website with my Ubuntu, I can load with other VPS and my personal PC. I need to fix this problem on my Ubuntu. THIS IS MY PROBLEM ONLY

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82737/discussion-between-user3770797-and-michael-hampton).